# jQuery: How to get the difference between time with 12hr format and time with 24hr format

Tags: jquery

I'm new in jQuery and I really don't know have any idea how to get this. I want to get the 12hr format result of the difference between time with 12hr format and time with 24hr format. Example: given the time "1:30:25 AM" and subtract it to "00:32:20", then the result should be "12:58:05 AM". Please help me to get this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Result in 24-hr format**

```
var dt = '1/1/2000 ';
var date = new Date(new Date(dt + '1:30:25 AM') - new Date(dt + '00:32:20'));
alert("24-hr format: " + date.toISOString().substr(11, 8));
```

Result: `00:58:05`

**Result in 12-hr format**

```
function timeFormat12Hr(date) {
    var hours = date.getUTCHours();
    var minutes = date.getUTCMinutes();
    var seconds = date.getUTCSeconds();
    var ampm = hours >= 12 ? 'PM' : 'AM';
    hours = hours % 12;
    hours = hours ? hours : 12; // the hour '0' should be '12'
    minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0' + minutes : minutes;
    seconds = seconds < 10 ? '0' + seconds : seconds;
    var strTime = hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds + ' ' + ampm;
    return strTime;
}

var dt = '1/1/2000 ';
var date = new Date(new Date(dt + '1:30:25 AM') - new Date(dt + '00:32:20'));
alert("12-hr format: " + timeFormat12Hr(date));
```

Result: `12:58:05 AM`

NOTE: I'm using string `'1/1/2000 '` to construct a Date object, but it could be any date because we're only interested in time portion of it.

See [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eqfe6u73/) for demonstration.

Comment: gyrocode.com is there a way to make a different clock in jquery other than the computer clock?this is without internet connection. the reason why i want this is i dont want to use the clock in computer because i think it is not reliable because you can adjust the time on computer right?the reason for this is i want to record a specific event using the time then after exactly 3 days i want to have a remainder sort of thing that will say the 3 days has lapse since i saved the data..

Comment: @HogRider, that seems to be irrelevant to the original question, please start a new one to get more attention, I'll see if I can help.

Comment: @Gyrocode.com , i don't know why but when I try to change the given to dt = "5/18/2015",  time in 12 hr format = "1:25:52 PM" and time in 24hr format = "00:00:03", the result is "12:NaN:NaN AM"

Comment: @MarkVincentManjac, it works for me, see [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eqfe6u73/2/).

Comment: @MarkVincentManjac, you missed space character between date and time, see http://jsfiddle.net/eqfe6u73/5/

Answer (score 0):

Some simple javascript should do the job. Once you have a date object you can output it in whatever format you want.

```
var year = 2015; var month = 5, var day = 18, var hours = 1; minutes = 30; seconds = 25;
var date = new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds);
var new_format = (date->getHours()+1)+'-'+date->getMinutes();
```

date returns 0-23 so you have to add +1 (this is why i tend to favor moment.js, as mentioned below)

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp (for other methods of creating date object)

Otherwise maybe give moment.js a try, it's awesome for date/time calculations.

http://momentjs.com/

Comment: `date->format('h:i:s a')` doesn't look like JavaScript at all, please explain?

Comment: Hmm you got me there. I seem to be mixing up the PHP and javascript date objects. I think the best practice way of choosing a format is to use date->getHours()+'-'+'date->getMinutes() etc. I'll update my answer.

Comment: That's not valid JavaScript either, sorry.